# Webforms: Inline Literals in .ascx preventing compilation

Tags: asp.net, webforms, ascx

I have the following snippit in my .ascx file:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="MyCompany.Modules.Discovery.ViewDiscovery"
    AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ViewDiscovery.ascx.cs" %>

<div id="ViewDiscovery_<asp:Literal ID="litModuleId" runat="server" />"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<asp:Literal ID="litControlPath" runat="server" />carousel-jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<asp:Literal ID="litControlPath2" runat="server" />discovery-widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var myData = <asp:Literal ID="litContent" runat="server" />;
        var myDiscovery = discovery('<asp:Literal ID="litControlPath3" runat="server" />');
        myDiscovery.json(myData);
        myDiscovery.init("ViewDiscovery_<asp:Literal ID="litModuleId2" runat="server" />");
    });
</script>
```

As you might be able to infer from the syntax highlighting (or rather, how broken it is), if I try to compile my CodeBehind file with this .ascx file, it fails horribly because it doesn't recognize the various literals that I have sprinkled around in the file, and thus my codebehind file fails to compile.  I have to remove them from their positions, put them at the end of the file unencumbered by their context in the page, compile, then revert to the original version.

Surely there is nicer way of going about putting literals in the page.

**EDIT:**  When I package my module up and install it on another instance of DotNetNuke (it works fine locally as long as I do that rigamarole when I compile it), it throws an error:

```
DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.ModuleLoadException: The tag contains duplicate 'ID' attributes
```

Related, or is there some other issue going on here?

**EDIT**: I have tried to use `<%=variable %>` but haven't gotten anywhere.  This is a snippit from my codebehind:

```
namespace MyCompany.Modules.Discovery
{
    partial class ViewDiscovery : PortalModuleBase, IActionable
    {
        public string strContent = "Insert Content Here!";

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            // Do stuff here!

            this.strContent = "My content!";
        }
    }
}
```

If I then do this in my ascx file:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="MyCompany.Modules.Discovery.ViewDiscovery"
    AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ViewDiscovery.ascx.cs" %>

<%=this.strContent %>
```

...nothing shows up on my page.  A peek at the context of 'this' in the .ascx file reveals it to be of type "ASP.viewdiscovery_ascx", not "ViewDiscovery" as I expected.

Answer (score 1):

I've not used DNN, but for what I think you're trying to do, inline expressions should work.

In your code-behind have some properties (or methods):

```
protected string ModuleId {get {return "1"; }}
protected string ModuleId2 {get {return "2"; }}
protected string ControlPath {get { return "path1/"; }}
protected string ControlPath2 {get {return "path2/"; }}
protected string Content {get {return "somecontent"; }}
protected string ControlPath3 {get {return "path3/"; }}
```

then you can use them as follows:

```
<div id="ViewDiscovery_<%= ModuleId %>" ></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ControlPath %>carousel-jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ControlPath2 %>discovery-widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var myData = <%= Content %>;
        var myDiscovery = discovery('<%= ControlPath3 %>');
        myDiscovery.json(myData);
        myDiscovery.init("ViewDiscovery_<%= ModuleId2 %>");
    });
</script>
```

Should generate the following HTML:

```
<div id="ViewDiscovery_1" ></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="path1/carousel-jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="path2/discovery-widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var myData = somecontent;
        var myDiscovery = discovery('path3/');
        myDiscovery.json(myData);
        myDiscovery.init("ViewDiscovery_2");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: That was one of the first things I tried.  No love.  See my original post.

Comment: So when you looked at the Html for the page those placeholders weren't being filled?  The class type you mentioned - "ASP.viewdiscovery_ascx" is generated by asp.net, it shouldn't break anything.  (You can override that though if you need to.)

Comment: I've updated my answer to show the HTML generated when I ran this.